# Creating a New Column with Heading in gtsummary

Tags: r, variables, gtsummary

I have a question regarding gtsummary in R. In the example attached, suppose I want to shift the heading "Grade" on a new column on the left of the characteristic column (so there will be a new column on the left with the Grade heading and then the column on the right (chracteristic) will have the same subsections I, II, and III). Only difference would be the main heading is separated from the subsection headings. Is there a way to do this in R?
[Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPvdg.png)
Adopted from: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/index.html
Was facing some difficulty as I was trying to implement something similar to this with respect to my project. Thanks!

Edit: To be more specific, my data deals with demographic variables, and I want an output like this (see attached). As seen here, race is separated from its subsections.

[example of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSixT.png)

Comment: Can you update the post with an example of what you'd like the layout of the table to be?

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg I just made an edit detailing a specific form I want with respect to the data I have

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would go about it!

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.0'

tbl <-
  trial |> 
  tbl_summary(
    include = c(age, grade),
    missing = "no"
  ) |> 
  # adding a new column called label2
  modify_table_body(
    ~ .x |> 
      dplyr::group_by(variable) |> 
      dplyr::filter(!(row_type %in% "label" & var_type %in% "categorical")) |>  # remove the header row for categorical variables
      dplyr::mutate(
        label2 = 
          dplyr::case_when(
            dplyr::row_number() == 1L ~ var_label
          ),
        label = 
          dplyr::case_when(
            variable == "age" ~ "Per year",
            TRUE ~ label
          ),
        .before = label
      ) |> 
      dplyr::ungroup()
  ) |> 
  # adding a header to the new column and setting its alignment
  modify_header(label2 = "**Variable**", label = "**Units/Level**") |> 
  modify_column_alignment(label2, "left") |> 
  # removing default indetations for categorical variables
  modify_column_indent(columns = label, undo = TRUE)

tbl |> as_kable() # convert to kable so table will display on SO
```

| **Variable** | **Units/Level** | **N = 200** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Age | Per year | 47 (38, 57) |
| Grade | I | 68 (34%) |
|  | II | 68 (34%) |
|  | III | 64 (32%) |

<sup>Created on 2023-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Will try to implement this later. I am wondering if you can assist with an additional question I have:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75850150/generating-p-values-for-subcategories-of-a-variable-using-gtsummary

Comment: It might be a silly question but wasn't really sure about the implementation

Comment: Hi Daniel. I am wondering if there is a way to add the age heading as a title within the  same "units/level" column? If so, how would the code look?

Comment: Also, I want to only use the methods from gt and gt summary, so was wondering if there's a way to add an age heading as a title for per year within the same units/level column using only gt and gtsummary methods

Comment: I am not sure what you have in mind. Probably best to make a separate post.