# Generating p-values for subcategories of a variable using gtsummary

Tags: variables, categories, p-value, gtsummary

I am using gtsummary to generate a stratified table of particular variables/subcategories. However, I am facing an issue generating p-values. As of right now, I have a p-value for race, but I instead would like the p-values for the sub-categories that go with race, and would like the race variable heading to be separated from the sub-categories.

[My Output Right Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7SCH.png)

[Output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fo8g.png)

I have tried the code (attached below), but seem to be getting errors. Essentially, I would need this to be fixed such that I have the "Race" heading separated from the sub-categories of race (so a new column on the left with a race heading, and then the column to the right of that would have the sub-categories with their p-values). Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Any advice is appreciated! I have attached a picture of the output I require above.

I have attached here a snapshot of some sample data:
[Snapshot of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LQKe.png)

I tried first selected the columns I needed (the above picture was a snapshot of part of the data) and tried to create a table using this code:

```
new_data = select(data, Gender, Age (Per year, median(IQR)), Race)

new_table <- new_data %>% tbl_summary(by = Gender) %>% add_overall() %>% add_p()
```

The issue at hand here is that I am getting p-values for age, but I need the p-values for the values contained within the race. I am not sure the best route to go by since I know that race is the variable and the others are sub-categories, but I need p values for the sub-categories.

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example, aka a reprex. This will include both code and data we can all run on our machines. Also, update your example output table to show what p-values you want to see....I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Hi there, I can't put the data on here because unfortunately its protected. However, what I essentially want is the race variable name to be a separate heading on the left, and then I need p-values for the white, black, bi-racial/multi-racial, and other race categories

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg I can try to take some screenshots for code

Comment: it doesn't need to be your data, just data illustrating the issue

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Hi Daniel, I attached a snapshot of some sample data and some code done.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Let me know if this makes it more clear.

Comment: The p-values I want to see are the p-value for age, and the p-values for biracial/multi-racial, black, other race, and white.

Comment: Create a dummy variable for each race level, then `add_p()` will add the p-values for each level. You can group the levels using this function if you like the look of this example: https://mskcc-epi-bio.github.io/bstfun/reference/add_variable_grouping.html